# App Crashes When I click on the Calculate Button to Display my Results

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, math, onclick

Working on a BMI Calculator that has a spinner that gets feet/inches as well as the user's weight.

Problem: When I click on calculate my app crashes I'm not sure what is going on. I know the logtcat mentions something about the onclick even though I had declared the button on oncreatview.

logCat:

```
 04-08 13:02:27.486 12353-12353/com.example.treycoco.calorietracker
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.treycoco.calorietracker, PID: 12353
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.example.treycoco.calorietracker.BmiFrag.onClick(BmiFrag.java:98)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

BmiFrag.java

```
     public class BmiFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
     Button BmiButton;

    public static EditText heightFT;
    public static EditText heightIn;
    public static EditText weightIn;

    //adaptors spinners

    ArrayAdapter<String> HeightFeetAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> WeightLBSAdapter;

    //references UI elements

    Spinner weightSpinner;
    Spinner heightSpinner;


     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bmi, container, false);

    heightSpinner= (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.HeightSpin);

    weightSpinner= (Spinner)myView.findViewById(R.id.WeightSpin);


    BmiButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.CalculateBmi);
    BmiButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    initializeSpinnerAdapters();
    loadLBVal();
    loadFTVal();

    return myView;
   }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {

       case R.id.CalculateBmi:


            final TextView tv4 = (TextView)
       getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TFDisplayBmi);

           /* str1*/
            String getWeightIN = weightIn.getText().toString();



             /* str2*/
            String  getHeightIN = heightIn.getText().toString();

            String getHeightFT = heightFT.getText().toString();



            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getWeightIN)) {



                weightIn.setError("Please enter your weight");
                weightIn.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getHeightIN)) {
                heightIn.setError("Please enter your height in Inches");
                heightIn.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getHeightFT)) {
                heightFT.setError("Please enter your height in Feet");
                heightFT.requestFocus();
                return;
            }


            else {

               float weight = getSelectedWeight();
                float height = getSelectedHeight();


                float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight,height);

                String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

                tv4.setText(String.valueOf(bmiValue + "-" +
                bmiInterpretation));


            }



            break;

    }
    }

     // retrieve the weight from the spinner control converted to kg
          public float getSelectedWeight() {
          String selectedWeightValue =
          (String)weightSpinner.getSelectedItem();

          return (float) (Float.parseFloat(selectedWeightValue) * 
          0.45359237);
      }


          public float getSelectedHeight() {
          String selectedHeightValue = 
          (String)heightSpinner.getSelectedItem();

         // the position is feets and inches, so convert to meters andreturn
        String feets = selectedHeightValue.substring(0, 1);
        String inches = selectedHeightValue.substring(2, 4);
        return (float) (Float.parseFloat(feets) * 0.3048) +
                (float) (Float.parseFloat(inches) * 0.0254);

     }


       private float calculateBMI(float weight, float height ) {

       //weight * 703f / (float)Math.pow(heightIN+12f*v,2);
       float bmi=  (weight / (height * height));

        float total= Math.round(bmi);



          return  total;
    }


        private String interpretBMI(float bmiValue) {

          if (bmiValue < 16) {
          return "Severely underweight";
          } else if (bmiValue < 18.5) {

           return "Underweight";
         } else if (bmiValue < 25) {

           return "Normal";
        } else if (bmiValue < 30) {

           return "Overweight";
            } else {
           return "Obese";
        }
    }



         public void loadLBVal() {
         weightSpinner.setAdapter(WeightLBSAdapter);
         // set the default lib value
        weightSpinner.setSelection(WeightLBSAdapter.getPosition("170"));
        }


        // load the feets value range to the height spinner
       public void loadFTVal() {
       heightSpinner.setAdapter(HeightFeetAdapter);
       // set the default value to feets
      heightSpinner.setSelection(HeightFeetAdapter.getPosition("5\"05'"));
    }

         public void initializeSpinnerAdapters() {

         String[] weightLibs = new String[300];

               for (int i = 1; i <= 300; i ++) {
             weightLibs[k--] = String.format("%3d", i);
             }
        // initialize the weightLibsAdapter with the weightLibs values
        WeightLBSAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 , weightLibs);




        String[] heightFeets = new String[60];
       // loading 3"0' to 7"11' to the height in feet/inch
          k = 59;
          for (int i = 3; i < 8; i ++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 12; j ++) {
            heightFeets[k--] = i + "\"" + String.format("%02d", j) + "'";
         }
        }
        // initialize the heightFeetAdapter with the heightFeets values
       HeightFeetAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), 
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, heightFeets);

      }


             @Override
           public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

           }

            @Override
            public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
           }
         }
```

Thanks Again . I'm still learning Android Studio and Java, This is my first time working on a app. Also , If the math looks off I apologize. I was researching different formulas.

Comment: which is your 98 line in `BmiFrag.java`

Comment: Instead of writing this much of code simply write BmiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ @Override public void onClick (View v)   //your method  } });

Comment: OMG Sorry Guys I over Looked it . I forgot I had EditText before I changed it to a spinner forgot to erase that code :/  Thats what happens when you stay up late working on a app lol. Sorry again guys, thanks though for taking the time on looking at the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you initialize all object related to your xml in oncreateview() method then you can use this object.
And check all the control view as you use in your xml like edittext or textview
so check the all objects to be initialize or not.

BmiButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Below code its right so Not need to change.

Comment: I forgot I had updated my xml . I had EditText before, but then I modified  my xml and used spinners instead. Damn... THanks for responding though

Answer (score 2):

You **haven't initialise** any of your `edittext` therefore on button click when you are doing this

```
String getWeightIN = weightIn.getText().toString();
```

you are getting null pointer exception. Initialise your edit text like you did for button and everything will be fine

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the callback function to BmiButton's Click Listener as the "OnCreateView()" method, when you state "this" in this line:

```
BmiButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Change "this" to "onClick(View v)", as in the example below, and you're good to go.

```
BmiButton.setOnClickListener(onClick(View v));
```

UPDATE: Although this will require you less editing, Nitesh Kumar's solution is the best way to go, as it won't require you going over a switch statement every time the user clicks a button, setting one callback function for each view clicked.